Creation of CloudFront signed URL using python3+ in Glue Jobs
Is it possible to create CloudFront signed URL with some time limits for one particular file located in S3 file in Glue Job using python3+?
I saw it's possible to do it in Lambda, but couldn't find anything in docs for Python and especially Glue job. Can anyone give some tips?
def load_private_key(key_path):
  with open(key_path, 'rb') as key_file:
    return serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

def rsa_signer(message):
  private_key = load_private_key('private_key.pem')
  signature = private_key.sign(
      message,
      padding.PSS(
          mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
          salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
      ),
      hashes.SHA256()
  )
  return signature


def get_signer_url(url):
    if key_pair_id:
        cf_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_pair_id, rsa_signer)
        current_date = datetime.now()
        retention_period = current_date + timedelta(days=93)
        signed_url = cf_signer.generate_presigned_url(url, date_less_than=retention_period)
        print(signed_url)
        return signed_url

url = "https://distr.cloudfront.net/path/to/resource"
signed_url = get_signer_url(url)

Getting errors like module 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding' has no attribute 'PSS', or 'hashes' not found, etc. Although I am using newest version. I am pretty new to all of these, and wanted to get some tips or advices.
